# How to randomize a date in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to back into a fake birthdate based on the age of a consumer. I'm using `lubridate` package. Here is my code:

`ymd(today) - years(df$age) - months(sample(1:12, 1)) - days(sample(1:31, 1))`.

I want to use this to generate a different dob that equals the age. When I run this inline it gives every row the same month and day and different year. I want the month and day to vary as well.

Comment: Because you are sampling vector of length 1 which is recycled

Comment: so I guess I need to build a loop to take a range of samples?

Comment: You can try  `months(sample(1:12, nrow(df))) - days(sample(1:31, nrow(df)))`

Comment: No loop required, take advantage of R's *vectorized calculations*. If you're doing this in a `dplyr` pipeline, perhaps replace `,1` with `,n()` in your two calls to `sample`.

Comment: The logic is completely wrong. The `years` function does not return a date but rather a number, which is not going to correspond with the scale of Date values that are returned by `ymd`. You might get closer by multiplying by 365 for years, 30 for months, and making the month and date samples the correct length.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a date with the year of birth at 1st of January and then add random duration of days to it.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(5)

df <- data.frame(age = c(18, 33, 58, 63))

df %>%
  mutate(dob = make_date(year(Sys.Date()) - age, 1, 1) +
                           duration(sample(0:364, n()), unit = "days"))
```

Comment: I think this is a good approach, but you shouldn't have to bother with `duration` and the unit specification. A `Date` is just a number anyway so you can just do `df %>% mutate(dob = make_date(year(Sys.Date()) - age, 1, 1) + sample(0:364, n()))`

Comment: Thank you both for contributing. This worked for me when I made the small change of allowing for sampling replacement.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, we can extract the year from the `age` column subtract it from current `year`, select a random month and date, `paste` the values together and create a `Date` object.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(age = sample(100, 5))

as.Date(paste(as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y")) - df$age, 
      sprintf("%02d", sample(12, nrow(df))),  
      sprintf("%02d", sample(30, nrow(df))), sep = "-"))

#[1] "1990-01-29" "1940-06-14" "1978-09-19" "1933-05-16" "1928-04-03"
```

However, in this case you might need to make an extra check for month of February, or to be safe you might want to sample dates only from 28 instead of 30 here.